DB2 Tablespace has no space SQLcode -960 SQLState=57011
Our application is inserting and updating records into a DB2 database. It's been running for about 3 years, and we encountered an error SQLcode -960 SQLState=57011 SQLERRMC=IS_SMALL_TS
The tablespace details are as follows:
Tablespace ID   = 5
Name    = IS_SMALL_TS
Tуре    =- Database managed space
Contents    = All permanent data. Large table space.
State   = 0x0000
Detailed explanation:   
Normal  
Total pages     = 894976
Number of useable pages = 894972
Number of used pages    = 893844
Number of free pages    =1128
High water mark (pages) =893844
Page size (bytes)   =16384
Extent size (pages) =4
Prefetch size (pages)   =4
Number of containers    =1

The Db2level info is as follows:
D: \IBM\SQLLIB\BIN>db2level
DB21085I
This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: "DB2")
uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11014" with level identifier
0205010F.
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.1.4050.859", "51911120160",
DYN1911120100WIN64 , and Fix Pack "5".
Product is installed at "D:\IBM\SQLLIB" with DB2 Copy Name "DB2COPY1".
We read through IBM Manual and tried a few thing including Alter tablespace IS_SMALL_IS increase 30 percent but don't see any changes. What can we do?

Have you tried AUTORESIZE, see https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=space-automatic-re-sizing-dms-table-spaces

This tablespace has autoresized enabled.

Is there a way to create additional containers?

please edit your question (do not use comments) with the plain text output of this SQL query: select type, count(*) from syscat.tables where tbspaceid=5 group by type order by 2 desc with ur   .  It's possible that your app needs to have housekeeping performed. Your DBA can add a stripe set via alter tablespace, but check the real limit being reached by examining the db2diag.log file(s) for your Db2-instance to look for ERROR and CRITICAL messages.

Alter tablespace IS_SMALL_IS increase 30 percent is an invalid command; no wonder it didn't do what you wanted. Have you tried alter tablespace ... resize?

@mao  what does " the select type, count(*) from syscat.tables where tbspaceid=5 group by type order by 2 desc with ur " do?
My apologies, the system is in a high secured environment with no access external system.  I literally type what the messages I saw on screen.

@EffendiBaba It counts the number of tables/views/etc. There are limits on total numbers per pagesize. Do follow-up and check db2diag, this is basic stuff that you (or your DBA if you have one) should be able to do. Otherwise you are wasting everybody's time.

I will, Let me get that. we need permission to run it as the system can still serve data to users.

After looking through the database tables and schema, we found an ingestion job to create temp tables that weren't removed. We had more than 55,000 temp tables. We removed it and recovered the spaces, and everything is working.

If that is the correct error message, my guess is you are creating all your tables,
maybe indexes etc. in IS_SMALL_TS tablespace.
Straight from the manual:

SQL0960C The maximum number of objects have been created in the
table spaces with the following names or identifiers
table-space-list.
Explanation You cannot create a new object in the table space because
the maximum number of objects for the table space has been reached.
User response
Specify a different table space in which to create the object or table. If the table space is a SYSTEM TEMPORARY table space, there
are too many concurrent temporary tables in use.

So, it's not about space as such, but how many objects (tables, indexes) you've created in it.
Run the query as suggested by mao which will show how many and what type of objects you have in that tablespace.  It varies by the pagesize, but the limit is over 50,000 objects per DMS tablespace. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=sql-xml-limits#r0001029__pglimit
As a quick(?) fix, you, or preferably your DBA, can relocate some tables to a new tablespace using the SYSPROC.ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE procedure. I would suggest you implement some regular housekeeping to either control the number of objects, or relocate them to other tablespaces.
